# How to get at offline store object

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm looking to retrieve the data that went into an offline store object, but it is difficult to get the simple object back after the marshaling.

```
var store = new qx.data.store.Offline("test offline");
store.setModel(qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel([{"hello":[1, 2, 3]}, {"hello again":[3, 4, 5]}]));

store.getModel().toArray().forEach(function(obj){  

  // How do I get this object back into something like obj["hello again"] -> [3, 4, 5]  
  console.log(obj); 

  /**
    console.log(obj.getHello()); // This works if I know the name, but I'm
    having the users create the name which could be complicated to piece
    back together in a getter    
  */
});
```

Here's a playground example:
http://tinyurl.com/p52pjgo

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Serializer for that:

`console.log(qx.util.Serializer.toNativeObject(store.getModel()));`

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks! I knew there had to be something - I just hadn't found it yet :-)